# Computing in the list of a tikz foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

If I say something along the lines of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\I{2}
\foreach \i in { \I+1, ..., 20 }
  \node at (\i,10) {+};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the message

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   +
l.560     \node[anchor=center] at (\i,10) {$+$};
```

How can I do arithmetic in the bounds of a foreach `...` range?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some possibilities with `foreach`. In your case, you can try the first one

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document} 
  \def\I{2}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i   [evaluate=\i] in {\I+1,...+1,19+1}
  \node[anchor=center] at (\i,0) {$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i   [evaluate=\i as \j using \i+1] in {\I,...,10}
  \node[anchor=center] at (\j,0) {$\j$};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i   [evaluate=\i as \j using \i*\i] in {\I,...,4}
  \node[anchor=center] at (\j,0) {$\j$};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would have never thought of `... + 1`  :)

Comment: This one is minimally disruptive, so far.

Comment: Hi Alain, how can I do this with non integer steps? I have tried with ...+0.1 but it does not work. I am using two arguments of newcommand to define the start and end point of the iteration list, so I do this:

\foreach \x in {#1+0.1,...+0.1,#2+0.1}

Comment: What does `...+1` mean?

Answer (score 4):

With eTeX, you can use `\numexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\I{2}
  \foreach \i in {\number\numexpr\I + 1\relax, ..., 20 }
  \node[anchor=center] at (\i,10) {$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo can use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\Start}{\I+1}` to compute the start point and then use `\Start` in the `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\I{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Start}{\I+1}
\foreach \i in { \Start, ..., 20 }
  \node[anchor=center] at (\i,10) {$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yup, I know that, and that is how I am doing it currently. But I have *many* such loops and the resulting construct is remarkably inelegant! :D