# Unable to shorten foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops, pgfmath

The following code is a simple double foreach statement that generates a staircase of coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{10-\i}
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\r} {
        \node at (\i,\j) {$(\i,\j)$};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wanted to simplify by not setting a macro and directly putting `10-\i` in the second `foreach` statement's range indicator. However, none of my attempts worked and threw a variety of errors.

Attempt 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,10-\i} {
        \node at (\i,\j) {$(\i,\j)$};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error Message:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

Attempt 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,(10-\i)} {
        \node at (\i,\j) {$(\i,\j)$};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error Message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

Attempt 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,{10-\i}} {
        \node at (\i,\j) {$(\i,\j)$};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error Message:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

Attempt 4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\pgfmathparse{10-\i}\pgfmathresult} {
        \node at (\i,\j) {$(\i,\j)$};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Error Message:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 11.
```

Is it impossible to do this task in this way?

Comment: Not really supported, stick to the setmacro method.  See linked questions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251195/using-dynamic-bounds-in-a-tikz-foreach?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment598704_251195

Answer (score 3):

The option `[parse=true]` does this job.

[image]

See more details in **Section 88** *Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement* of [PGF/TikZ manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i[parse=true] in {0,...,10}
\foreach \j in {0,...,10-\i} 
\path (\i,\j) node{$(\i,\j)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My personal comment: TikZ's `foreach` is quite flexible; however, TikZ/TeX is a typesetting system with limited computation, so it is far from natural syntax in comparison with some strong programming languages, such as Python, Asymptote. For instance, the following Asymptote code is very natural. (also note that the [Asymptote code can be embbed into .tex document](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/LaTeX-usage.html))

[image]

```
// Asymptote has a handy "for" loop
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
size(12cm);
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
for (int j=0; j<10-i; ++j)
label("$($"+string(i)+","+string(j)+"$)$",(i,j),blue);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also the `evaluate` option for `\foreach` that has the same effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \r using 10-\i] in {0,...,10} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\r} {
        \node at (\i,\j) {$(\i,\j)$};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly put `\the\numexpr10-\i\relax` in the `\foreach` and Ti*k*Z will expand it (note however that the computations possible in `\numexpr` are very limited, basically only +, -, *, /, and parentheses).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,10} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\the\numexpr10-\i\relax} {
        \node at (\i,\j) {$(\i,\j)$};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```